# Angular ngStyle Parser Error: Unexpected token [, expected identifier or keyword

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I need to be able to pass a dynamic string using the `fieldName` in order to get an attribute within the item object. In order to make it easy to duplicate the issue I have given a small example. The problem is this syntax works properly with angular 12.2.5 as I checked but did not work with angular 12.0.0 or below. I can simply call a function but I know this is not good for performance. Is there an alternate way to write this syntax for older angular applications?

**HTML**

```html
<p [style.background]="item?.[fieldName]">
  Some Text
</p>
```

**ts**

```js
item =  { warn: 'yellow', success: 'green', error: 'red' };
fieldName = 'success';
```

Error looks like this

```
Parser Error: Unexpected token [, expected identifier or keyword at column 20 in [{background: item?.[fieldName]}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use ternary operator `?:`:

```html
<p [style.background]="item[fieldName] ? item[fieldName] : ''">
  Some Text
</p>
```

Comment: Welcome. Consider also upvoting and accepting my answer if it helped you.